# What lines i should add to spark-defaults.conf to be able to use phoenix from pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

I have installed phoenix-4.7 and it works properly with hbase (i have copied the jars the to hbase folders). Now i would like to use phoenix with pyspark and according to the documentation (see below) i need to add 2 lines to spark-defaults.conf:

- spark.executor.extraClassPath
- spark.driver.extraClassPath

What exactly i should insert to be able to use it from spark?

I am using HDP2.6 and python 2.6  and spark 2.0

installation guide says the following:

Spark setup

> To ensure that all requisite Phoenix / HBase platform dependencies are
>   available on the classpath for the Spark executors and drivers, set
>   both ‘spark.executor.extraClassPath’ and ‘spark.driver.extraClassPath’
>   in spark-defaults.conf to include the ‘phoenix--client.jar’
>
> Note that for Phoenix versions 4.7 and 4.8 you must use the
>   ‘phoenix--client-spark.jar’. As of Phoenix 4.10, the
>   ‘phoenix--client.jar’ is compiled against Spark 2.x. If
>   compability with Spark 1.x if needed, you must compile Phoenix with
>   the spark16 maven profile.

error message i get when trying to write dataframe to phoenix:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.phoenix.spark. Please find packages at spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: error message i get when trying to write dataframe to phoenix:

: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.phoenix.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: ok, it seems i have overcomplicated it.

spark.executor.extraClassPath "your path to phoenix client jar"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the problem has been solved for you. This is what worked for me. 
setting the following in the spark-defaults.conf in my conf directory under spark directory. In my case it was phoneix 4.8.1 working with spark 1.6 and hence 4.8.1 libraries have been added to the path. You would need to add your version of Phoenix jars accordingly.

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/local/apache-phoenix/phoenix-4.8.1-HBase-1.2-client.jar:/usr/local/apache-phoenix/phoenix-spark-4.8.1-HBase-1.2.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/local/apache-phoenix/phoenix-4.8.1-HBase-1.2-client.jar:/usr/local/apache-phoenix/phoenix-spark-4.8.1-HBase-1.2.jar
```